# How to Get value of disabled @Html.CheckBox VB MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a checkbox in .net MVC and I need to get the value of this checkbox but it is disabled, this is my code:

```cs
<div class="editor-field">
   @Html.CheckBox("cbTratamientoFiscal", New With {.class = "checkbox", .disabled = "disabled"})
</div>
```

I tried something like this in jquery:

```js
var tratamientoFiscal = $("#cbTratamientoFiscal").val();
// also:
var tratamientoFiscal = $("#cbTratamientoFiscal").is(":checked");
// or:
var tratamientoFiscal = $("#cbTratamientoFiscal").attr('checked');
```

And nothing is working.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the actual html when it gets rendered?

Comment: <input class="checkbox" disabled="disabled" id="cbTratamientoFiscal" name="cbTratamientoFiscal" **value="true"** type="checkbox"><input name="cbTratamientoFiscal" **value="false"** type="hidden">

Comment: You have two elements with the same name, 'cbTratamientoFiscal', bith the checkbox and the hidden inputs. That is likely leading to the trouble. the name attribute selector in the answer below will find both elements.

Comment: `var tratamientoFiscal = $("#cbTratamientoFiscal").is(":checked");` works fine - and here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ybs1a9j/) to prove it. (the hidden input has nothing to do with it)

Answer (score 3):

This will give you a true/false result if the name attribute is 'cbTratamientoFiscal':

`$("input[name='cbTratamientoFiscal']").is(':checked')`

Comment: Hello @SamTyson ! when it gets rendered the html is like this:  
 
<input class="checkbox" disabled="disabled" id="cbTratamientoFiscal" name="cbTratamientoFiscal" value="true" type="checkbox"><input name="cbTratamientoFiscal" value="false" type="hidden">

Comment: `$("#cbTratamientoFiscal").is(':checked')` should give you true/false since only one of the inputs has that id.

Comment: Both appear at the same time, but the value attribute is different, the input hidden always have value="false". Can I try this?: $("input[name='cbTratamientoFiscal', type='chekbox']").is(':checked');

Comment: You could also use `$("input.checkbox").is(':checked')` since you added the checkbox class.